# How to highlight some words from a custom dictionnnary using CodeArea from RichTextFx

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

What I want to do is pretty simple in my head, but might be very hard to do.

Currently, I did set up RichTextFx in my JavaFX project and created a code area. What I'd like to do is make some words a certain color depending on a custom dictionary that I'd make. For example, I'd have an array list for all the words that should be red, and I'd somehow link it to the code area.

I have absolutely no idea how to do that, and if it even is possible.
Anyway, I'd very much appreciate it if you could help me!

Comment: Isn't this exactly the "Java Keywords Demo" [here](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/tree/master/richtextfx-demos#automatic-highlighting-of-java-keywords)?

Comment: I don't think so. The example highlights based on java keywords color. I want to be able to set a custom color for whatever word. I want that if someone types in "pizza" it displays pizza with #4a88c7 as the color

Comment: That example has different colors for different parts of the code (purple for keywords, red for parentheses, etc.)

Comment: Did you read what I said? I want to be able to choose a *specific* color for a *specific* word. I want "pizza" to be #4a88c7

Comment: So adapt that example. Your question is off-topic: it falls under [this category of questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). "I don't know where to start" is not a "specific programming problem".

Comment: It's not "I don't know where to start", it is "I have a base, how do I make a custom thing that isn't referenced anywhere? (or I can't find it)"

Comment: So if you know where to start, post a [mre] and identify the specific problem you are having. This question is not answerable as it stands (what would an answer look like?).